# MVC DropDownListFor null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This model is used to define a view:

```
namespace OnlineStore.ViewModels
{
    public class SubCategoryVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Parent Category Name is required")]
        public virtual string ParentName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoryNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Inside controller:

```
public ActionResult createSubCategory()
{
    SubCategoryVM model = new SubCategoryVM();
    var cNames = db.Categories.ToList();
    model.categoryNames = cNames.Select(x
        => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Name,
            Text = x.Name
        });
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult createSubCategory(int? id, SubCategoryVM model)
{
    SubCategory sc = new SubCategory();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        sc.ParentName = model.ParentName;
        sc.Name = model.Name;
    }
    return View();
}
```

and View:

```
@model OnlineStore.ViewModels.SubCategoryVM        

<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentName, Model.categoryNames, "--Please select an option--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

This code is throwing a null-reference exception on line `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentName, Model.categoryNames, "--Please select an option--", new { @class = "form-control" })` saying:

Model.categoryName (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

Please help me debug it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: irrelevant here. sorry

Comment: Suggestin: Your model property "categoryNames" seems to be null, make a null check before returning from the controller and return an empty list if null

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? There is one cause of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object": something is null.

Comment: @AndreasGustafsson -  if "categoryNames" is null, how come I'm seeing a list in the dropdownlist when the get method stretches the view?

Comment: @John - and that is what I'm asking. If its null, how come I'm seeing  a list inside the dropdownlist to select from.

Comment: Does your exception appear after you submit your form, or when you load the form at the beginning? (I suspect the former)

Comment: @Rafalon - after I submit the form.

Comment: Re populate the list again after the submit.

Comment: @AndreasGustafsson just look at his code, answer is **no**. R.K: check your Post method, your list is null there

Comment: @RK you have your answer then

Comment: @Rafalon Yeah I changed my comment. (sorry my misstake)

Comment: @RK repopulate the dropdown again in the submit method before returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is when you are posting the form and returning the View with the form data in case of invalid form, `categoryNames` in the model is becoming null and you have to repopulate the `categoryNames` before returning the view with model again.

So update your `createSubCategory` post method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult createSubCategory(int? id, SubCategoryVM model)
{
    SubCategory sc = new SubCategory();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        sc.ParentName = model.ParentName;
        sc.Name = model.Name;
    }

    var cNames = db.Categories.ToList();
    model.categoryNames = cNames.Select(x
        => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Name,
            Text = x.Name
        });

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Have to admit that I've done this for trillions of times, but always forget all about it. Thanks for the help.